# Fastest method of finding words in a collection with wildcard letters

Tags: c#, hashset

I have ~200,000 words that I need to find matches in with words that can contain any number of letter wildcards. I also need the option to look up words without any wildcards.

I've separated the words into collections by length:

```
static readonly HashSet<string>[] _validWords = { 
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), // 3 letter words
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), // 4 letter words
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), // 5 letter words
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), // 6 letter words
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), // 7 letter words
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), // 8 letter words
    new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)  // 9 letter words
};
```

To search for a specific word is simple:

```
public static bool IsValid(string word) {
    return word.Length >= GameplaySettings.Instance.MinWordLength && _validWords[word.Length - 3].Contains(word);
}
```

This is my current implementation of finding wildcard words, using a Regex (eventually I'd like to get *all* matching words, but for now just finding one (or none) is fine.):

```
public static bool IsValidRegex(string pattern, int length) {
    pattern = $"^{pattern}$";

    foreach (string word in _validWords[length - 3]) {
        if (Regex.Matches(word, pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline).Count > 0) { return true; }
    }

    return false;
}
```

There can be any number of wildcards (e.g. *all* letters can even be wildcards), and it's currently not performing as well as I'd hope.

So I'm wondering if there is more efficient method!

Thanks for any help/suggestions!

Comment: Using a hashet doesn't provide any benefit here. Perhaps you need to come up with some kind of tree structure that you can search.

Comment: _"my attempted implementation unfortunately did not work"_ -- since `HashSet<T>` doesn't help at all in this scenario, your question would be better if you provided a proper [mcve] showing what you tried, along with a detailed explanation of what that actually did, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - am I wrong thinking that a HashSet for looking up specific entries is faster than iterating an Array or List? It's a HashSet because of this required functionality, and rather than duplicating the data I was looking for a solution using the same container.

Comment: A HashSet is faster for lookups because it doesn't iterate through all of its items: it uses the hashcode of the object you're looking up to find the correct partition internally within the hashset and then compares each item with a matching hashcode for equality until it finds the one in question. So instead of comparing `.Count` items, you'll probably just compare 1 (depending on hashcode collisions). Iterating a hashset isn't faster than iterating an array or a list, and that's exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @Llama Yeah that was my understanding, so I'm using the HashSet because I do need to look up specific words, and separately I also need to find wildcard matches. I've updated the question with my current implementation to hopefully explain it a bit better.

Comment: By wildcard, do you mean one letter or many? Instead of using string & Regex, build a tree of some kind to store your words. maybe `class Node{ bool validWord; Dictionary<char,Node> next; }`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Many, from 1 to the full length of the word!

Comment: I mean, do you expect one wildcard "A*Z" to match against multiple letters "ABCDEF...XYZ" or only consume a single letter like "AQZ" (eg like hangman).

Comment: Oh sorry, one wildcard is a single letter. So "H\*L\*O" would be looking for a five letter word where indices 1 and 3 can be any letter.

Comment: @stuntboots: _"am I wrong thinking that a HashSet for looking up specific entries is faster than iterating an Array or List?"_ -- `HashSet<T>` is good for lookups when you can define equality uniquely per object. If you also have that need, it's fine to use that for the collection. But it doesn't help at all for wildcard-oriented searches, which is the scenario you seem to be asking about. Your question should omit mention of the `HashSet<T>`, as that's just a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your wildcards can only match one letter, the problem isn't too hard. If you needed to support variable length substrings, I'd suggest you go and read some of the scientific literature on how regular expressions work.

This is a fairly basic 2nd year comp-sci "data structures and algorithms" exercise. Using a `Dictionary` in every `Node` probably isn't going to be the fastest / most memory efficient. But I would tackle the problem like this;

```cs
class Node
{
    public bool endWord;
    public Dictionary<char, Node> next;
}

public class Words
{
    private Node root = new Node { endWord = false };
    public const char wildcard = '_';

    public void DefineWord(string word)
    {
        var node = root;
        foreach (var c in word)
        {
            if (node.next == null)
                node.next = new Dictionary<char, Node>();
            if (node.next.TryGetValue(c, out var nextNode))
            {
                node = nextNode;
            }
            else
            {
                node = node.next[c] = new Node { endWord = false };
            }
        }
        node.endWord = true;
    }

    private bool IsValid(ReadOnlySpan<char> word, Node node)
    {
        if (word.IsEmpty && node.endWord)
            return true;
        if (node.next == null)
            return false;

        if (word[0] == wildcard)
        {
            word = word.Slice(1);
            foreach(var n in node.next.Values)
            {
                if (IsValid(word, n))
                    return true;
            }
        } else if (node.next.TryGetValue(word[0], out var nextNode))
            return IsValid(word.Slice(1), nextNode);
        return false;
    }

    public bool IsValid(string word)
        => IsValid(word, root);

    public static void Test1()
    {
        var words = new Words();
        words.DefineWord("APE");
        words.DefineWord("APPLE");
        words.DefineWord("BEAR");
        words.DefineWord("BEER");
        words.DefineWord("PEAR");
        words.DefineWord("PEER");
        words.DefineWord("PEERS");

        Assert.True(words.IsValid("APE"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("APPLE"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("PEAR"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("PEER"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("PEERS"));
        Assert.True(!words.IsValid("PLIERS"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("PE_R"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("_EAR"));
        Assert.True(words.IsValid("_E_R"));
    }
}
```